# Why did my "if" statement cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm making a basic cipher for an assignment, and trying to ensure that the cipher only applies to alpha text. It was recommended I use "isalpha()" for this, so I attempted this in the following code:

```
if( isalpha(cipherInput))
{  
   for (int i = 0, n = strlen(cipherInput); i < n; i ++)
   {
        printf("%c", (cipherInput[i] + k % 26));               
   }
}
else
{
    printf("%s\n", cipherInput);
}
```

This returned "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when I tried inputting anything, so I did some googling and found out how to debug, which returned

```
Core was generated by `./caesar 3'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0804879e in main (argc=2, argv=0xbfd14604) at caesar.c:21
21     if( isalpha(cipherInput))
(gdb) ^CQuit
```

Which apparently means I'm messing around with memory stacks in weird ways. Why would this happen from a simple if statement? All the examples I found online dealt with pointers.

Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);

    if( k <= 0 )
    {
        printf("You must input a non-negative integer.\n");
        return 1;    
    }


    printf("What do you want to cipher?\n");
    string cipherInput = GetString();

   if( isalpha(cipherInput))
   {  
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(cipherInput); i < n; i ++)
    {

             printf("%c", (cipherInput[i] + k % 26));               
    }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", cipherInput);
    }

    printf("\n");

}
```

Note: `cs50.h` can be found at http://dkui3cmikz357.cloudfront.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.h

Comment: `int isalpha(int c);`

Comment: What is the definitions of `string` and `GetString()`?

Comment: This is actually C, not C++, which makes `string` very confusing given that this is not C++ `std::string`.

Comment: -1 for not knowing what language you are compiling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`isalpha()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha) function tests *a single character* for being alphabetical or not. It does not test an entire string. There are many such character-classification functions in the standard library; they all work on a single character at a time.

You're passing a C++ object, which is then treated as a (probably *very large*) character value, seemingly causing an out-of-bounds access inside `isalpha()`.

You *need* to enable all compiler warnings, and make sure you `#include <ctype.h>`, you should have gotten warnings for this.

Comment: Thank you. That I can't pass a whole string through a char tester seems like a real "duh" thing, dunno why I didn't realize it.

Comment: Wait a minute: how *could* a C++ object be treated as a very large character value in the first place ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I have no idea. :(

Answer (score 3):

The function `isalpha` expects an `int` and you are passing a `string`, which is a `char *` according to [`cs50.h`](http://dkui3cmikz357.cloudfront.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.h)

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Why would isalpha expect an int? According to https://cs50.harvard.edu/resources/cppreference.com/stdstring/isalpha.html it's used to check if something is alpha, right? How could an int be an alpha (char?)

- oh, I do see though that the "string" thing made by cs50.h is really a char with a pointer thing going on, so that would be why it caused s egmentation fault. So I need to convert each part of the "string" into separate chars, then check each with isalpha, right?

Comment: @komali_2 `isalpha` is specified as taking an `int` by the standard. The last sentence of your comment sounds right :)